# ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN failed for table because it is a ledger table and the operation would need to modify existing data that is immutable

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, ledger-tables

I wanted to update a column from date to datetime.

When I run the query I get the following messages:

> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN failed for table 'Transaction' because it is a ledger table and the operation would need to modify existing data that is immutable.
>
> Failed executing DbCommand (40ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> DECLARE @var0 sysname;
> SELECT @var0 = [d].[name]
> FROM [sys].[default_constraints] [d]
> INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] [c] ON [d].[parent_column_id] = [c].[column_id] AND [d].[parent_object_id] = [c].[object_id]
> WHERE ([d].[parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[Transaction]') AND [c].[name] = N'Date');
> IF @var0 IS NOT NULL EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE [Transaction] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var0 + '];');
> ALTER TABLE [Transaction] ALTER COLUMN [Date] datetime NOT NULL;

I understand what the problem is, but I do not have a solution.

Do I have to delete the database and restart from scratch? I need to use the same column name so creating another column and then copy the data to the new column is not an option.

I cannot seem to delete or update the corresponding ledger tables and their records.

What would be the recommended approach? And does using ledger tables means that I will never be able to drop or alter any columns?

Any comments or answers would be much appreciated!

Comment: "Do I have to delete the database and restart from scratch?" - not the database, just the table.

Comment: "I cannot seem to delete or update the corresponding ledger tables and their records." - yes, _that's the point_ - if historical data could be changed willy-nilly that would defeat the purpose of cryptographically-secured ledger tables.

Comment: [Existing columns can't be altered in a way that modifies the format for this column.
We allow changing:
Nullability.
Collation for nvarchar/ntext columns and when the code page isn't changing for char/text columns.
The length of variable length columns.
Sparseness.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/ledger-limits)

Answer (score 0):

If you have created an append-only ledger table, you won't be able to update or delete records. Only insert is allowed. You can still drop or alter columns in a table but there are some considerations that you will need to take into account.

See [Ledger considerations and limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/ledger/ledger-limits?view=sql-server-ver16#schema-changes-consideration)

Comment: For me, you aren't offering a solution to the problem described in the question. Hence, in my opinion, this is not really an answer. I would say that it's more of a comment. Note that you should not post a comment as an answer simply because you don't yet have enough reputation points to be able to post a comment.